# Using DecimalFormat with Android Development

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have looked at ways to solve this I am still very new to java and just looking into it and am kind of diving head first into it and ran into a problem. The problem I am having is that I want to change the number of Decimal places that is output by this "Tip Calculator" I am making and I also want it to format in currency using the $ symbol. My code is below I am using

```
public class TipCalculatorActivity extends Activity {

      DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
      EditText costofmeal, tippercent;
      TextView tiptotal, totalbill; 
      Button calctipbtn;
      BigDecimal costNum, percentNum, billNum;

      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            calctipbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calctipbtn);
            costofmeal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CostofMeal); 
            tippercent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PercentTipText);
            tiptotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tiptotal);       
            totalbill = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalbill);   
            calctipbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                costNum = new BigDecimal(costofmeal.getText().toString());
                percentNum = new BigDecimal(tippercent.getText().toString());

                tiptotal.setText(costNum.multiply(percentNum).toString());
                System.out.println(money.format(tiptotal));

                costNum = new BigDecimal(costofmeal.getText().toString());
                billNum = new BigDecimal(tiptotal.getText().toString());


                totalbill.setText(costNum.add(billNum).toString());
                System.out.println(money.format(totalbill));
            }
          });   
     }
}
```

My method of thinking was basically that I could have the output of the equation and then I could use the `money.format` and call the `textview` that I used and it would format it to the `DecimalFormat` that I had. Instead now the app force closes when I hit the calculate button the log errors I get are

```
06-04 21:32:57.242: D/AndroidRuntime(1905): Shutting down VM

06-04 21:32:57.242: W/dalvikvm(1905): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0x40015578)

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905):     at java.text.NumberFormat.format(NumberFormat.java:308)

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905):     at 
java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:714)

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905):     at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905):     at com.verge.tipcalc.TipCalculatorActivity$1.onClick(TipCalculatorActivity.java:50)

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2537)

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9157)

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905):     at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)

06-04 21:32:57.257: E/AndroidRuntime(1905):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

All I want to do is round the `totalbill` and the `tiptotal` to 2 decimal places and have it formatted in currency I have tried like 3-4 methods I looked up and none of them have been successful.

Comment: Please include the entire list of logcat errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lYou will need to do it like this -

```
DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("00.00");
money.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);// you can also use DOWN here if you dont need to round up the decimal.
.
.
System.out.println(money.format(new Double(totalbill.getText())));
```

Whats important here i think you missed is `new Double(totalbill.getText())` . You cannot pass totalBill directly as it is textView. You will need to parse it into Double or Flot and than pass it to formatter.

Also `$` can be appended later to the text.

```
totalbill.setText("$" + totalbill.getText())
```

Comment: alright Kshitij I tried out yours the error I am getting is

Syntax error on Token(s) Misplaced Construct(s)"

Syntax Error on token "."

Comment: at which line are you getting the error? what does totalbill.getText() returns? is it String?

Comment: also you will need to do the same for tiptotal.

Comment: Yes it is string I added that and the second error went away but I still have an error on line 48 and that is where 

        money.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);

the error is the same as above Syntax error on Tokens and misplaced constructs

Comment: This might not have been the best Idea of me diving right into this I should have just bought a book and read it haha sorry about this

Comment: also I have added the tip total no errors on any of that just on where the money.setRoundingMode(RoundMode.UP); is on line 48

Comment: money.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP); should ideally not generate this error. Check the line before it. Maybe you can find something there. Maybe you missed a ';' or added some extra keyword .......Also, you can just remove that line to check if it works otherwise

Comment: Thanks again I removed it and the app doesn't crash anymore but there is no formatting on the numbers I will check the line before it anyways you have been a great help and steered me in the right direction I will mess with it thanks a ton!

Comment: i am glad i was of help. please accept the answer if you find it useful :)

Comment: also i think you are putting money.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);  outside the method. If thats the case, you need to put it inside some method.

Comment: alright one last thing I got the error now "The method setRoundingMode(RoundingMode) is undefined for the type DecimalFormat" and I didn't have it in a method I fail :( like I said I need to go read a book

Answer (score 0):

u can try this code

Convert ur BigDecimal value like this so that its decimal value will be upto 2 places

```
   BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal( costNum);
   bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```